# Azure Automation Complex Schedule

Tags: azure, azure-automation

Is there a way we can specify a Complex Schedule for an Azure Automation Runbook?

Currently we can only configure if the Runbook needs to run Hourly,Daily,Weekly / Monthly. I want to set up something like "Run from Tuesday to Saturday, Daily at 1 PM".

Only way I can think of right now is to code it inside the RunBook.

Please let me know if there's any other way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automation offers weekly and monthly schedules in the new Azure portal.  [This service announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/automation-scheduling-feature-update/) talks a bit about how you can use weekly/monthly schedules to do what you are looking for.  You can also use the [New-AzureRMAutomationSchedule cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603577.aspx) to create weekly schedules and specify the days (use the ByWeekly parameter set).

[image: WeeklySchedules]

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

You have to write custom powershell script within your runbook and schedule your runbook to run every hour or probably everyday at 1PM.

The custom powershell script will have code which checks if a day is NOT Sunday, Monday and Saturday!